# How to set a keyframe from another keyframe in LESS

Tags: less, css-animations, keyframe

I have some legacy keyframes that I want to re-namespace.

E.g I have legacy code:

```
@keyframes bulge {
  50% {}
}
```

And I want to do something like:

```
@my-ui-bulge: @bulge;
```

**Is this possible?**

Comment: If you mean you need to reuse an existing keyframe (that you *can't* modify) under another name - then no, it's impossible. You'll have to modify those one way or another (keyframes name itself can be a variable and/or may be reassigned via mixin or ruleset).